# How to create a windows 10 complete restore point?

Tags: windows-10, backup, iso-image, restore, clone

I need to make a complete copy of my windows 10 so that I can get back to exactly how it was at the time of the creation of the backup/snapshot.

By searching the web it seems that the windows restore point won't get me back to exactly how the computer was.

I found making an image or cloning the hard drive to be the most suitable options.

Are there any other options?

What is the difference between them?

I don't mind if making the backup will take a long time but it's most important for me that getting back to the backup will be as fast as possible (I will be making 1 restore point and get back to it about once a day)

Comment: The way you create a Restore Point on Windows 10 is identical that to that of any version of Windows that has Restore Points.  What have you tried exactly?  Restore Points are not "complete copies" by the way.  If you want a complete copy of your Windows installation a Restore Point will NOT achieve that goal.

Comment: The only way to get a complete Windows 10 image is to make a complete backup.  Acronis or like product.

Comment: I prefer Macrium Reflect Free, no cost app and does an excellent job.

Comment: As you state , so called "Restore Points" only back up certain Windows files. There are many free and paid applications to create an image of a disk, with **all** data, i.e., your own files and operating system files and the boot sectors. Some free apps I've used include Macrium Reflect Free and DriveImage XML; https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree and https://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching online and reading many reviews and options I chose to use **Redo Rescue** because it's an **open source, totally free, constantly updated and well supported**.

Macrium Reflect (which seams to be the most marketed option all over the web) isn't open sourced and its free version doesn't have more features then Redo Rescue.

I successfully tested Redo Rescue. It was extremely simple and friendly to use, with great interface and instructions.

I also looked at similar options and these are my findings:

CloneZilla - Great for deploying the clone on many computers simultaneously but doesn't have an interface (GUI) so it's for more advanced users intending on deploying massively.

Rescuezilla - Started off as a fork of Redo Rescue but seems to be much less used and updated.

Answer (score 1):

No, system restore points can't do this.

You have to use a feature like System image backup, which is built in to windows. And using that you can backup your whole system including settings, to external hard drive or network location. Later you can use the System Image Restore feature of WinRE to restore your system exactly to the older backup point.

Also there are many third party tools like Macirum which can do the job even better.